# Does Amazon Cloudfront support HTTP pseudostreaming?

Tags: http, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am building an CDN on Amazon Cloudfront. Can anyone tell me if it supports HTTP pseudostreaming? Sometimes I get lost in the documentation and terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
CDN on Amazon Cloudfront does not support HTTP pseudostreaming.

However, it does support byte-range in request headers. You will need a  player that can work with byteranges.